# LINQ To Objects GroupBy method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How does LINQ To Objects GroupBy method work? Does it look throught the whole collection for each key? Is there any way to say to GroupBy method that collection is sorted?

Answer (score 2):

GroupBy, if done sensibly, would work in a single forwards only pass. A basic implementation (not theirs) would be something *comparable* to:

```
var data = new Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>(comparer);
foreach(var item in source) {
    var key = keySelector(item);
    List<TValue> list;
    if(!data.TryGetValue(key, out list))
    {
        data.Add(key, list = new List<TValue>());
    }
    list.Add(itemSelector(item));
}
```

That basically groups by key, creating a list for each unique key, containing the values.

You *could* do things like compare to the last-seen key (to help with sorted data), but... you'd need to profile to know if it is worthwhile.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean that a full pass through the sequence is done when the enumerator is created and that the enumerator is blind to any changes in the source afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Let's just look at the overload

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
);
```

as its the simplest to understand. Effectively the code will do something like this:

Enumerate through `source`

For each `element` in source, map element to `key = keySelector(element)`

See if `key` is in a dictionary keyed by `TKey`
    if it is not, add the `key` with the value a `List<TSource>` and first item `element`
    else, get the `List<TSource>` associated to key and add `element` to the list

Now you have a dictionary mapping `TKey` -> `TSource` and can easily produce a sequence of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`.

So something like

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, List<TSource>> dictionary;
foreach(var element in source) {
    key = keySelector(element);
    List<TSource> list;
    if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list)) {
        list = new List<TSource>();
        dictionary.Add(key, list);
    }
    list.Add(element);
}
```

From here you can easily yield a sequence of `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>`.

I don't see why you think the list being sorted matters.

Comment: IF the list were sorted, we could yield IGrouping without processing the whole list

Comment: if the list were sorted by the key, and you knew it, you could build up an IGrouping object and then `yield return` it as soon as the key value changes, then start a new IGrouping. @Idsa - it wouldn't be too hard to make a `GroupBySorted` extension method and then profile it to see if it has any practical benefit over the regular `GroupBy`...

Answer (score 0):

> Does it look throught the whole collection for each key?

No.  The implementation of GroupBy is O(n), not O(n^2)